# Comparing strings with user-created string class

Tags: c

For this assignment I had to create my own string class.  I initially wrote the compareto method to compare two string but return whichever is overall larger.  What I want to do is compare and return which one is alphabetically larger i.e. comparing two strings, for example: smith and htims.  With the way I designed the compareto method is that the result will be that they are equal.  What I want to do is tell me which one comes first alphabetically, so for my example htims would come first.  I understand how to do this in Java or even in C with using the `<string.h>` library, I am just confused as to how to do this myself.

EDIT: I just wanted to note that I am not looking for code answer, rather a nudge in the how I should write the code.

```
int compareto(void * S1, void * S2){
    String s1 = (String S1);
    String s2 = (String S2);
    int i, cs1 = 0, cs2 = 0; //cs1 is count of s1, cs2 is count of s2

    while(s1->c[i] != '\0'){ //basically, while there is a word
        if(s1->c[i] < s2->c[i]) // if string 1 char is less than string 2 char
            cs2++; //add to string 2 count
        else (s1->c[i] > s2->c[i]) //vice versa
            cs1++;
        i++;
    }

//for my return I basically have

        if(cs1>cs2){
         return 1;
    }
    else if(cs2 > cs1){
         return 2;
    }
    return 0;
```

here is mystring.h

```
typedef struct mystring {
    char * c;
    int length;

    int (*sLength)(void * s);
    char (*charAt)(void * s, int i);
    int (*compareTo)(void * s1, void * s2);
    struct mystring * (*concat)(void * s1, void * s2);
    struct mystring * (*subString)(void * s, int begin, int end);
    void (*printS)(void * s);

} string_t;
typedef string_t * String;
```

Any suggestions, all of my google searches involve using the `<string.h>` library, so I've had no luck.

Im using this to traverse through a linked list and remove the person whose last name matches the person the user is trying to delete.
Here is my test code to help clarify my problem (Note that compareto is in the remove function):

```
int main() {
    Node startnode, currentnode, newnode;
    int ans, success;
    String who;
    who = newString2();

    startnode = (Node) malloc(sizeof(pq_t));
    startnode->next = NULL;
    currentnode = startnode;
    ans = menu();
    while (ans != 0) {
        switch (ans) {
        case add:
            newnode = getStudent();
            startnode = insert(newnode, startnode);
            break;
        case remove:
            printf("Enter the last name of the person you want to delete : \n");
            scanf("%s", &who->c);
            startnode = removeStudent(startnode, who, &success);
            if (success == 0)
                printf("UNFOUND\n");
            else
                printf("permanently DELETED\n");
            break;

        case view:
            printf("Now displaying the list : \n");
            displaylist(startnode);
            break;
        }
        ans = menu();
    }
}

Node removeStudent(Node head, String who, int * success) {
    Node p, l; //p = pointer node, l = previous node
    Student current; //Im using generics, so I have to case the current node->obj as a student.
    String ln, cln; //the last name of the person I want to remove, and the last name of the current node

    p = head;
    l = p;
//there can be three cases, p->first node, p->last node, p->some node in between
    if (head->obj == NULL) { 
        printf("The list is empty\n"); //when the list is empty
        *success = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    while (p != NULL) {
        current = (Student) p->obj;
        cln = current->ln;
        if (ln->compareTo(who, cln) == 0) {
            if (head == p) { //when there is only one node
                head = head->next;
                free(p);
                *success = 1;
                return head;
            } else if (p->next == NULL) { //last node
                l->next = NULL;
                free(p);
                *success = 1;
                return head;
            } else {
                l->next = p->next; //middle
                free(p);
                *success = 1;
                return head;
            }
        }
        l = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    *success = 0;
    return head;//couldnt find the node
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what ordering you want when searching the list. Do you want alphabetical, ASCII-betical (http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCIIbetical-order.html) or something else? Do you want to change your `compareto` function, or define another? Also, why are you passing `void *` to the functions, rather than `String *`, which will make them type safe? Did you put function pointers in `string_t` to implement inheritance or encapsulation? What's the reasoning for your Hamming-distance-like `compareto` algorithm?

Comment: My goal is to sort through alphabetically.  What I'm using this function for is to remove a person from a linked list by their last name.  The reason for void* is because we have to do this assignment with generics to understand how they work.

Comment: Your question would be **greatly** clarified by a few examples.  If you write the examples in the form of unit tests, you'll even be able to see if your code is right on those examples.

Comment: I updated my post to help better clarify things

Comment: @meepz: I'm not convinced `void *` are right for the arguments to the function pointer members of `string_t`, since the `void *` represent strings rather than a parameterized type. It also doesn't make sense for the `compareto` function, since you're casting to `String`s and access string specific members.

Comment: @meepz: you could use `compareto` with multiple types if you were to limit yourself to method calls (such as `charAt`) in the methods, and the type of the formal parameters was compatible with the actual parameters, but that's more plain polymorphism than generics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming). Also, you'd then need to worry about class layout (also called the "mold" by Cohen and Gil, http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Class_analysis_criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing the following pairs of strings:

"ABC" vs "DEF"

"ADF" vs "BBB"

"ABC" vs "CBA"

What results do you get? More importantly, why? How do these results compare to what you want to get?

(You should first work it out in your head. Work out the values of c1 and c2 for each step of the comparison loop.)

Comment: The results I get are: 2, 1, 2.
These results just tell me which string is cumulatively larger compared to what I want to get which is alphabetically larger (or in order).  I know how to write this in java, and with <string.h>, I'm just confused as to how to write it myself.  I'll keep trying to think it out though

Comment: Ask yourself how YOU know which string comes first: "ABC" or "ACB". Then, "AABC" vs "AACC'. You do it the same way you want the computer to do it, so slow down a little and figure out what you're doing. Turning that into code should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

First, `ln` isn't properly initialized in the sample `removeStudent()`, so calling `ln->compareTo` will probably cause a segfault. Hopefully, `ln` is properly initialized in your actual code.

To define an ordering on the strings, you can first define what's known in database circles as a "collation": an ordering on characters. You can implement the collation as a function (called, say, `chrcmp`), or inline within your string comparison function. The important thing is to define it.

Generally speaking, an ordering on a type induces a [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on sequences of that type: to compare two sequences, find the first place they differ; the lesser sequence is the one with the lesser element at that position.

More formally, suppose sequences are indexed starting at 0. let **a** and **b** be sequences of the base type of lengths **m** and **n**, respectively. The lexicographic order a ≤ b is:

- a < b where a<sub>i</sub> R b<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>j</sub>=m<sub>j</sub> for all 0 ≤ j < i
- a < b if a is a prefix of b
- a=b if m=n and a<sub>i</sub>=b<sub>i</sub> for all 0 ≤ i < m

Where "a is a prefix of b" means m < n and a<sub>i</sub> = b<sub>i</sub> for all 0 ≤ i < m.

The advantage of this approach is you can write a comparison function that will work with any [homogeneous](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HomogenousContainer) sequence type: strings, lists of strings, arrays of integers, what-have-you. If you specialize the comparison function for null-terminated strings, you don't need to worry about the cases for prefixes; simply have '\0' be the least character in the collation.

From a general comparison function (called, say, `lexiCompare`), you can define

```
lexicCompareString (a, b):
    return lexicCompare(a, b, chrcmp)
```

and set a String's `compareTo` member to `lexicCompareString`.